# iTextSharp - Check PDF Document Properties - Content Copying, Content Copying For Accessibility

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-reader

I'm trying to check whether PDF document to be uploaded has the following document properties - Content Copying & Content Copying For Accessibility Allowed / Not Allowed using iTextSharp PDFReader. Is there any property to verify this functionality. I have pasted a sample code which is NOT returning the expected result.

**Looking for solution using iTextSharp**

[image: PDF Document Properties]

Sample Code:

```
            using (PdfReader r = new PdfReader(@"xxx\yyy.pdf"))
            {
                if (PdfEncryptor.IsScreenReadersAllowed((int)(r.Permissions)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Content Accessibility Enabled");
                }

                if (PdfEncryptor.IsCopyAllowed((int)(r.Permissions)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Copy Enabled");
                }

                if (PdfEncryptor.IsAssemblyAllowed((int)(r.Permissions)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Document Assembly Enabled");
                }
            }
```

Comment: typo corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The `Permissions` value you check is initialized only for encrypted PDFs. The sample dialog you pasted here, on the other hand, shows *No Security*, so your sample document is not encrypted. Thus, the `Permissions` value is not set to any meaningful value.

None of the restrictions a PDF can get as part of the encryption process apply to non-encrypted PDFs. Thus, you might want to update your tests to

```
if (PdfEncryptor.IsScreenReadersAllowed((int)(r.Permissions)) || !r.IsEncrypted())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Content Accessibility Enabled");
}

if (PdfEncryptor.IsCopyAllowed((int)(r.Permissions)) || !r.IsEncrypted())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Copy Enabled");
}

if (PdfEncryptor.IsAssemblyAllowed((int)(r.Permissions)) || !r.IsEncrypted())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Document Assembly Enabled");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Is there any property to check if Page Extraction is allowed / not allowed when the PDF document has no security method set?

Comment: @user7121382 There essentially are three types of restrictions: ***A** The ones one can set as part of the encryption process; for not encrypted PDFs these obviously do not apply. **B** The ones one can set as part of the signing process or that are inherent to it; these restrictions only apply to allowed or disallowed changes to the document. **C** The ones imposed by the PDF viewer program.* As your example shows, "Page extraction" is an example of **C**: Your example is neither encrypted nor signed (otherwise you would have said so, wouldn't you), thus there only remains **C**...

Comment: @user7121382 And what is allowed in a given viewer depends on the viewer itself. E.g. you appear to have opened the document in the Adobe Acrobat Reader. In the full Adobe Acrobat most likely everything is allowed. Essentially what one has to be aware of is that that "Document Restrictions Summary" actually is a "Document Restrictions Summary as Interpreted by this Viewer" and that some of its information cannot be derived from the PDF alone...