# iTextsharp PDF Document Properties

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-reader

I need to check if the PDF has the following properties before uploading PDF process starts,

1) PDF should not be password protected
2) PDF should not have the Document Properties - Page Extraction & Content Copying & Content Copying for Accessibility NOT ALLOWED.

I'm able to check whether the PDF is password protected or not using PdfReader IsEncrypted property. But when the PDF has no Security Method set, how can I check the above mentioned document properties. Permissions is useful only when the document is encrypted. (using iTextsharp dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PDF can be encrypted in different ways. The most common way is by adding one or two passwords:

1. An owner password: everyone can open the PDF, but there might be permissions in place.
2. A user password: only people who know either the user password or the owner password can open the document.

If there's a user password in place, iText can't open the document, and a `BadPasswordException` will be thrown:

```
public static boolean isPasswordProtected(string file) {
    try {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);
        return false;
    } catch (BadPasswordException bpe) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If there's only an owner password in place, then you can ignore that password by setting a special parameter. See [Can I use iText to merge PDF's with Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462808/can-i-use-itext-to-merge-pdfs-with-permissions)

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

Note that `PdfReader` also has an `isEncrypted()` method, see the [PageInformation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#264-pageinformation.java) example in chapter 6 of "iText in Action - Second Edition."

This answers the first part of your question: how can I check if a PDF is encrypted or not?

As for the permissions: once you've opened a password protected PDF, you can use the `getPermissions()` method to know which permissions are in place:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file);
int permissions = pdfReader.getPermissions();
```

This `int` is actually a bitset. The `PdfEncryptor` class has a method `getPermissionsVerbose()` that explains what each bit means:

```
public static String More ...getPermissionsVerbose(int permissions) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("Allowed:");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING) buf.append(" Printing");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS) buf.append(" Modify contents");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY) buf.append(" Copy");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS) buf.append(" Modify annotations");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN) buf.append(" Fill in");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS) buf.append(" Screen readers");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY) buf.append(" Assembly");
    if ((PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING & permissions) == PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING) buf.append(" Degraded printing");
    return buf.toString();
}
```

For instance, if you want to know if assembly is allowed, you need to check the value of `PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY & permissions`.

Comment: Can these permissions be set on the document without encrypting the document? I'm not aware how this works. My intention is to check the document properties irrespective of whether the document is protected or not.

Comment: @user7121382 *"Can these permissions be set on the document without encrypting the document?"* Which exactly are *these permissions*? As I have tried to explain in answer to your [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40883003/1729265), some permissions indeed are only possible to set as part of encryption (even though the PDF viewer user might not recognize the encryption because a default password is used).